# Can I make a html video player support video different formats like .avi?

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, html5-video

Is it possible to add video codec for formats that the browser doesn't support such as .Avi?
Basically, I want to play videos of different formats but because I don't know the formats for all the videos and I can't change them, i want the player to be able to support as many as possible.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: yes, in theory. Media Source Extensions allow you to feed the media buffer, but it's a non trivial task to build decoders for 'any' format so unless you've experience with this I'd suggest either using a commercial transcoding service or run an ffmpeg instance to transcode to a known playable format

Comment: @Offbeatmammal can i transcode the video using ffmpeg and at the same time stream it at the video player?

Comment: @ChrisTsironis for mp4 not recommended. you could output HLS/DASH using something like `ffmpeg -i source.avi -c:v libx264 -crf 21 -preset veryfast -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ac 2 -f hls -hls_time 4 -hls_playlist_type event stream.m3u8` but better to transcode when uploaded rather than lose quality trying to do quickly